# what is wrong in my JSON array format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

What is wrong with my JSON data shown below?

```
var myJSON = [
  {"x":108,  "y":58, "w":431, "h":23},
  {"x":203, "y":121,  "w":240, "h":47},
  {"x":64, "y":183, "w":138, "h":9},
  {"x":140,  "y":208, "w":85, "h":7},
  {"x":51,  "y":225,  "w":263,  "h":135},
  {"x":51,  "y":376,  "w":75, "h":7},
  {"x":51,  "y":393, "w":263, "h":123},
  {"x":51, "y":532,  "w":263,  "h":112},
  {"x":51, "y":655,  "w":263,  "h":112},
  {"x":334, "y":183,  "w":68,  "h":9},
  {"x":333, "y":508,  "w":262,  "h":112},
  {"x":417, "y":645,  "w":95,  "h":7},
  {"x":332, "y":664,  "w":264,  "h":103},
  {"x":441, "y":488,  "w":47,  "h":7},
  {"x":333, "y":508,  "w":262,  "h":112}
];
```

When i try to parse it `var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);`, i am getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of
>   the JSON data 
>   [Learn More]

Comment: You're trying to parse an Array Object rather than a JSON Array as String.

Comment: If you want to convert it into a string, use `JSON.stringify(myJSON)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) expects a JSON string and parses / converts it to an object.
- [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) expects on object and stringifies / converts it to a JSON string.

You're trying to use `JSON.parse()` to parse an object, which makes no sense.

Because your data already is an object ([an array is an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)), you can immediately assign it to `myObj`, skipping the parsing step :

```
var myObj = [
  {"x":108,  "y":58, "w":431, "h":23},
  {"x":203, "y":121,  "w":240, "h":47},
  {"x":64, "y":183, "w":138, "h":9},
  {"x":140,  "y":208, "w":85, "h":7},
  {"x":51,  "y":225,  "w":263,  "h":135},
  {"x":51,  "y":376,  "w":75, "h":7},
  {"x":51,  "y":393, "w":263, "h":123},
  {"x":51, "y":532,  "w":263,  "h":112},
  {"x":51, "y":655,  "w":263,  "h":112},
  {"x":334, "y":183,  "w":68,  "h":9},
  {"x":333, "y":508,  "w":262,  "h":112},
  {"x":417, "y":645,  "w":95,  "h":7},
  {"x":332, "y":664,  "w":264,  "h":103},
  {"x":441, "y":488,  "w":47,  "h":7},
  {"x":333, "y":508,  "w":262,  "h":112}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` works only if you want to parse a `string`to javascript object. In case you already have a javasript object (or array), you don't need JSON.parse:

```js
var myJSON = `[
  {"x":108,  "y":58, "w":431, "h":23},
  {"x":203, "y":121,  "w":240, "h":47},
  {"x":64, "y":183, "w":138, "h":9},
  {"x":140,  "y":208, "w":85, "h":7},
  {"x":51,  "y":225,  "w":263,  "h":135},
  {"x":51,  "y":376,  "w":75, "h":7},
  {"x":51,  "y":393, "w":263, "h":123},
  {"x":51, "y":532,  "w":263,  "h":112},
  {"x":51, "y":655,  "w":263,  "h":112},
  {"x":334, "y":183,  "w":68,  "h":9},
  {"x":333, "y":508,  "w":262,  "h":112},
  {"x":417, "y":645,  "w":95,  "h":7},
  {"x":332, "y":664,  "w":264,  "h":103},
  {"x":441, "y":488,  "w":47,  "h":7},
  {"x":333, "y":508,  "w":262,  "h":112}
  ]`; 

console.log(JSON.parse(myJSON));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse JSON object as a JSON object, you don't need to do that if your myJSON is already an object.

If its stored as a string, then that `JSON.parse()` would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to parse a JSON object. Are you sure you don't want to covert it to a string format (using JSON.stringify())???

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the resulting object before it is returned.

```
 var json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
    obj = JSON.parse(json);

    console.log(obj.count);
    // expected output: 42

    console.log(obj.result);
    // expected output: true
```